# Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\----\revue\src'

Tags: firebase, vue.js

It just comes up with this error:

> Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users---\revue\src'

I do not know whats wrong with it. I have just been trying to get `firebase` to work for a long time now , and i think i know how to do it?

Like write to the database but this just doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix it ? Here is the main code.

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Welcome to ReVue!</h1>
    <input v-model='titleEdit'>
    <input type="submit" @click.prevent="">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyADctvC6_ieKCaJ5ZHJhDqPkL-psudyUMw",
  authDomain: "revue-8a64b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "revue-8a64b",
  storageBucket: "revue-8a64b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "663593574772",
  appId: "1:663593574772:web:72c466aff95b39e3e64c21",
  measurementId: "G-FPX766L85J"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const databaseRef = firebase.database();
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data: function(){
    return {
      titleEdit:'',
      title:''
    }
  },
  methods:{

  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```